# Make hyperlink content clickable in Excel after an export from Drupal7

Tags: php, excel, drupal-7

i am using the Drupal 7 "Views Data Export" module, and i want to make Hyperlink content clickable in Excel after export from a View.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information, possibly some of your code you have written? This looks like you could solve it with google.

Comment: There is no code for instant i am using The CMS Drupal7 with this two modules "Views" and "Views Data Export" for exporting in excel, that creates a .xls file with all my content, but i would like to have the URLs clickable in the cell like if i do so in excel: =HYPERLINK("http://stackoverflow.com/";"Stackoverflow"). Drupal use "PHP" code to export datas.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your url field in views_data_export views page using rewrite output and paste there something like
=HYPERLINK("[your_field]"; "[your_text]")

Answer (score 0):

**I finally create a drupal 7 export module:**

1. The sql request
2. Construct the result as a html table (Excel accept html datas)

   `<table>
     <tr>
       <th>Title_A</th>
       <th>Title_B</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Content_A</td>
       <td>Content_B</td>
     </tr>
   </table>`
3. Add headers to create a *".xls"* file with the html table

   `header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xls");`
4. For the clickable links make a html "href"

   `<td><a href='Content_URL'>Content_Link_Name</a></td>`